# "Extending" an interface to allow for optional usage of function in instances

Tags: haskell

I am trying to add optional spacing into generated source code, the source code is generated into several languages like Python and Java.

I have an abstract file (non final code language specific) I have a function for creating the "if" control statement. It is similar to:

```
ifConditions :: (RendererSym r) => (Doc -> Doc) -> Doc -> Doc -> Doc -> [(SyValue r, MBody r)] -> MBody r -> MStatement r
ifConditions a startIf c d (x:xs) z = .....
```

That part is not too important here other than in the body of this function there is something like
`<+> startIf` which I want to turn into `<> optionalSpace startIf`

No I could have instead simply changed `<+> startIf` to `<> startIf` and gone into each language specific file and changed the following

```
instance ControlStatements JavaGenCode where
  ifConditions = G.ifConditions a startIf b c
```

into the following if I wanted a space. prepSpace could be imported from an "abstract" file into each language specific rendering file as needed.

```
prepSpace :: Doc -> Doc 
prepSpace x = space <> x

instance ControlStatements JavaGenCode where
  ifConditions = K.ifConditions a (prepSpace startIf) b c
```

Instead is it possible (a good idea) to add this to the ControlStatements class?

```
class (BSym r, VSym r) => ControlStatements r where
  ifConditions :: [(SyValue r, MBody r)] -> MBody r -> MStatement r
  optionalSpace :: Label -> MStatement r
```

Then in each language specific rendering file:

```
instance ControlStatements JavaGenCode where
  ifConditions = K.ifConditions a startIf b c  --same as before
  optionalSpace = K.optSpace Empty
```

and in K file:

```
optionalSpace :: (RendererSym r) => Label -> MStatement r
optionalSpace n = ...
```

My main confusion is tying it all back into `ifConditions`. Now that

1. I have `optionalSpace` in the `ControlStatements` class
2. I have an instance in `instance ControlStatements JavaGenCode`, as needed
3. `optionalSpace` is defined in K

How can I tie this back into the `ifConditions` function, so that I can use `<> optionalSpace startIf`? What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of missing context (why is `optionalSpace :: Label -> MStatement r` being used like it's `Doc -> Doc` (in `<> optionalSpace startIf`)? Why is `ifConditions` a method if you're always going to implement it using `K.ifConditions`? ...)

A shot in the dark.

Try defining a wrapper around `K.ifConditions` in the file containing the `ControlStatements` class,

```
class ControlStatements r where
  ifConditions :: ...
  optionalSpace :: ...

kifConditions :: ControlStatements r => ...
kifConditions a startIf b c = K.ifConditions a (optionalSpace startIf) b c
```

Comment: The OP might not even need a wrapper.  The class `ControlStatements` looks abstract, and it doesn't appear to violate that abstraction to have `K.ifConditions` require the `ControlStatements r` constraint directly in its type signature, after which it is free to call `optionalSpace` directly.